# Deserialize a transient member of an object to a non-null default in Java

Tags: java, serialization

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable {
  private transient Map<String, Object> myHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to ensure that when an object of the above class is deserialized the member myHash will be set to a new empty Map rather than be set to null?

Comment: is it not setting the default values already? is this a singleton class?

Comment: @fatih Deserialization doesn't call your constructors or your field initializers. It's an important lesson, it can save you hours of hassle debugging seemingly good code that suddenly ceases to work.

Comment: it wont call any functions or constructors but apperantly it is not executing class scope inited object inits as well. learning new things everyday. thx.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable {
    private transient Map<String, Object> myHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();

        myHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation to go with the code would improve your answer. Code-only answers only make sense to those who already know what they're doing!

Answer (score 11):

What about adding a [readObject](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) method like this:

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable {
  private transient Map<String, Object> myHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  ...
  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();     
    myHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
}
```

That should sort you out.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your own custom `readIn` method and explicitly create a new `Map<T>` as explained in the [Java Serializable documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). That article should describe how to do what you're looking for; check the section entitled **Customize the Default Protocol**.

Comment: That link is dead.