# Deserialize a transient member of an object to a non-null default use Kryo

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable {
    private transient Map<String, Object> myHash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ...
}
```

I find this question

> [Deserialize a transient member of an object to a non-null default in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811615/deserialize-a-transient-member-of-an-object-to-a-non-null-default-in-java)

but use standard deserialize in java, it works. but it seems not invoke `readObject` in kryo.

Answer (score 0):

When you will call objectInputStream.readObject(); while reading your saved object  (from file) MyObj's readObject() will be called (if there).

You don't need to call that method (MyObj's readObject()) explicitly on MyObj's object..

Comment: I understand no need to call that method, but if kryo won't call that method like java standard deserialization, it'll have no chance to gurantee transient object is not null

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use externalizable interface that extends serializable and override its writeExternal() method.

```
Class abc implements Externalizable
  {
    transient String name;
    private int age;

    public abc(){ }
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)       throws IOException
    {
 out.writeObject(name);
 out.writeInt(age);

         }
     public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws   IOException,ClassNotFoundException
    { 
 name=(String)in.readObject(name);
 age=(in.readInt(age);

          }

}
```